SWI PL CS library redirect input stream
I have been trying to run the example below and the Sread function seems to be executing in an infinite loop. I am using visual studio 2022, prolog 7.4.2 x64 and SwiPlCs 1.1.60605.0 library.
http://lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/Generated/html/M_SbsSW_SwiPlCs_PlEngine_SetStreamFunctionRead.htm
Am I doing something wrong or there is an issue with the library?
Many thanks!

Changed this  byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s); to use UTF8 instead of Unicode and it's now working for me...

When you want to add details to your question, you have to click on "Add a comment" under your question.
